# Restrict the AutoCompleteTextView predictions to only restaurants

Tags: java, android, google-places-api, autocompletetextview

I've got an Android app that allows the user to perform a details search based on a restaurants name. However, depending on the users input, the predictions can contain places, countries, etc. Where can I add a restriction to only check for restaurant names?

My current code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE
                    + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            System.out.println("URL: " + url);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            place = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
//                  System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(
//                          "description"));
//                  System.out
//                          .println("============================================================");
                    resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                            "description"));

                 String description = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
                 String placeId = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("place_id");
                 place.put( description, placeId);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }
        return resultList;
    }
```

Comment: Star the issue, [Allow Places types in autocomplete](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3538), if you would like to see this enhancement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [place types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3) the closest you can get is the `establishment` filter. You are going to have to perform a search rather than an autocomplete in order to use the `restaurant` filter.

Using the Places API for Android [PlaceComplete](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceComplete) sample I tried passing in `Place.TYPE_ESTABLISHMENT` and `Place.TYPE_RESTAURANT` to  `AutocompleteFilter.create` to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `place_type` in your search, use this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) to find the supported types.